# Android google maps not working

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using the android google maps apis, the application compiles fine, but when i deploy it on the phone it can't load the tile, this is the error I'm getting over and over.

```
10-18 22:30:46.260  21460-21776/com.nescafe.nescafe2.nescafe2 D/REQUEST﹕ Error processing: com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.b.d@4284ddc0 not retrying
10-18 22:30:46.267  21460-21776/com.nescafe.nescafe2.nescafe2 D/REQUEST﹕ Retrying: com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.au@42a95a00
10-18 22:30:50.174  21460-21776/com.nescafe.nescafe2.nescafe2 D/REQUEST﹕ Connection opened to:https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api
10-18 22:30:50.181  21460-21776/com.nescafe.nescafe2.nescafe2 D/REQUEST﹕ Open Connection
10-18 22:30:50.346  21460-21776/com.nescafe.nescafe2.nescafe2 D/REQUEST﹕ DRD(39): 62|147
```

I double checked the API_KEY, and it is correct, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: We need more information to help you. Please show us the whole log.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your SHA-1 is wrong. If you are using eclipse do this steps.

**Go to tab 'Window' and click on 'Preferences'.**

On **window Preferences**, click on **Android**(Left Panel),and click '**Build**'. Check if the SHA-1 is the same of Google Console

Answer (score 0):

If SHA-1 is correct, the package on the web console is ok and the key is correct (and you changed the key after the first run), try to clear ALL data of the application.
Sometimes the key get cached somewhere (or something similar, I got an error like this)